# Десериализация с помощью GSON

Tags: java, android, gson

Всем привет! Недавно увлекся программированием, и появилась необходимость десериализовать данные с помощью GSON (либо чего-то более подходящего), чтобы положить всё это в БД.

Ответ сервера примерно такой (получаю в jsoup Document):

```
  теги html и body
  4887854839908
  <!---->
  <!---->0
  <!---->6879
  <!---->0
  <!---->
  <!--json-->
  {"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value",
    "list":[
       ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6"],
       ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6"],
       ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6"],
       .....
       ..... 
       .....
       ],
    "key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"}
   <!---->
      ...... //Здесь куча div классов
    <!---->
    <!--json-->
    {"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value",
      "key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"}
    <!---->
      ...... //опять div классы
```

Отсюда нужно вытащить массив значений "list" и несколько "key":"value". Как всё это проще и грамотнее преобразовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, что JSON будет всегда отделяться от остального HTML при помощи данных в вашем примере тегов:

```
    String jsonCommentStart = "<!--json-->"; // это начало
    String jsonCommentEnd = "<!---->";       // это конец
    String str = "<html>...</html>" //ваша исходная строка
```

Тогда мы получим строку с JSON, отсекая все лишнее:

```
    int jsonContentsBegin = 
str.indexOf(jsonCommentStart) + jsonCommentStart.length(); //начало содержимого
    Log.i("TEST", "onCreate: " + jsonContentsBegin);
    //строка, начинающаяся сразу после <!--json-->
    String json = str.substring(jsonContentsBegin); 

    //окончание JSON
    int jsonContentsEnd = json.indexOf(jsonCommentEnd) + jsonContentsBegin; 
    Log.i("TEST", "onCreate: " + jsonContentsEnd);
    String jsonContents = str.substring(jsonContentsBegin, jsonContentsEnd);
```

Строка, содержащаяся в переменной `jsonContents` -  и есть искомый json. Очищаем от лишнего и преобразуем в JSON:

```
jsonContents = jsonContents.trim();
try
{
    //объект, из которого вы сможете получать нужные данные

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonContents);
    Log.i("TEST", "onCreate:  JSON: " + object.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.i("TEST", "onCreate: " + e);
}
```

Чтобы получить второй, третий и т.д. JSON объект из HTML, возьмите подстроку, начинающуюся с позиции `jsonContentsEnd`. С этой подстрокой проведите те же действия, что я указывал выше.

Чтобы вытаскивать какие-то данные из JSON, используйте код:

```
object.getString(key); // - для строки
object.getJSONArray(key);// - для массива
```

Где `key` - это ключ какого-то либо значения. Больше информации [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)